# Python how can I make all if's lead to the else

Tags: python

```
import time
import os
import math
import string
from random import *

def hasNumbers(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)

print("Password checker")
password = input("Enter password: ")

if len(password) > 8:
    if password[0].isupper():
        if hasNumbers(password):
            print("Password is secure!")

else:
    print("Password not strong enough!")
```

If I put "BobBob123" it sais "Password is secure!" which is fine. If I put bob it goes to the else. If I put "Bob123" it doesn't show anything.

Comment: have you tried the `and` keyword, as in `if len(password) > 8 and password[0].isuuper() and hasNumbers(password):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to have them all in line, like so:

```
if len(password) > 8 and password[0].isupper() and hasNumbers(password):
    print("Password is secure!")
else:
    print("Password not strong enough!")
```

this makes use of the `and` keyword to check all condiitons on one line, rather than having them nested.

Comment: No problem, mark the answer as accepted whenever you can so people know that you have had your question solved :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the `if`s to lead to one `else` then you need one `if`:

```
if len(password) > 8 and password[0].isupper() and hasNumbers(password):
    print("Password is secure!")
else:
    print("Password not strong enough!")
```

though it is rather unfriendly to reject a password without saying why.